# Why Gas Used By Txn is different when invoking the same function in the same smart contract？

Tags: ethereum

I have seen some transactions in etherscan.io.But I have found that even invoking the same function in the same smart contract, the gas used by txn are different.I try to found that maybe the input data result in it.Really?

Answer (score 0):

The input data might be different, but also the state stored in the smart contract might be different (and change e.g. the number of times a loop iterates).  Also, if storing nonzero data in a state variable that previously held zero data, or vice versa, will change the gas usage.  For example, a simple function that toggles a boolean variable will not use the same amount of gas on any two consecutive calls.

Check out https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ for future questions like this!

Answer (score -1):

Each time you invoke a function in contract that requires state change in the block,it would cost x amount of gas , so every time you call different or same function in a contract that requires a state change,you would see that x amount of gas is being deducted along with its taxation Id.This is the reason you see different Txn on same function.

More about Gas and Transaction in the link below.  http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

Comment: I am new in Ethereum，so how can we learn the state of  the function in transaction？Thanks